# Why MINGW64 gcc produce much SLOWER code than MSVC for this source

Tags: visual-c++, mingw-w64

I compile this short example example.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    time_t t = clock();
    double x = 0;
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<1000000000u; i++) x += sin(i);
    printf("%f\n", x);
    printf("%f s\n", ((double)(clock() - t)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    return 0;
}
```

with:

1. MINGW64 (MSYS2) (v.13.1.0)
   gcc -O3 example.c

Produced example.exe about 250kB and when is started the program executes for about 45s

2. Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 (C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.35.32217.1 for x64)
   cl /O2 example.c

Produced example.exe about 139kB and when is started the program executes for about 22s

Why the optimized Release production from MSVC is about 50% FASTER!

I try another options - for example gcc /Ofast of --fast-math, but the result is not better for gcc.

Comment: What you are *actually* comparing are the C runtime implementations of the sin() function.  The MinGW project made a historical mistake of not implementing (or borrowing) their own C runtime.  Relying instead on msvcrt.dll, an old dog that has not been improved over the past 25 years.  Yes, it is that much slower for sin().  Microsoft made the "universal run time" (aka UCRT) available to help such projects break their dependency on msvcrt.dll but as yet MinGW has not taken advantage of it.

Comment: But this is enormous problem - if compiled with gcc mathematical software is two times slower than compiled with mscv!

Comment: @HansPassant, MinGW-w64 does support UCRT. See MSYS2 package `mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gcc`.

Answer (score 1):

The inside of your loop will have its hands full with `printf()`. The MinGW standard library `printf()` is slower than the one provide by Windows API. But it's more compatible with other platforms in some cases.

Try building with `__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO` set to `0`, either by using compiler flag `-D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=0` like this

```bash
gcc -O3 example.c -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=0
```

or by inserting

```c
#define __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO 0
```

at the top of your source file (before the first `#include`).

Then both builds (GCC+MinGW-w64 and MSVC) will be using the same `printf()`, so you can compare apples with apples.